# Can I use "System.Currency" in .NET?

Tags: .net

Is it possible to use system.currency. It says system.currency is inaccessible due to its protection level. what is the alternative of currency.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) data type..

The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.

Comment: You know, it's not "more precision" that is important, it's the type of precision.  Decimal is based on a 10-base scale and will always exactly represent a decimal number within it's range.  Floats types however are based on a binary scale and may be describing a fraction that is not part of base 10

Answer (score 8):

Use Decimal.  All of the functions that Currency provides are static methods on Decimal, FromOACurrency, and ToOACurrency.

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible via reflection but the reasons that it's there are for **`FromOACurrency()`** and **`ToOACurrency()`** static methods on **`System.Decimal`**, which is for convering from/to the Ole Automation `Currency` type that Visual Basic 6 uses.

Answer (score -3):

You can't actually use Decimal for Currency. You'll face bigger problems later on when you divide. Say if you have $1 split into 3 which is 1/3 = 0.33(rounded), but 3 x 0.33 = 0.99 != 1. It might be small, but when you do that in accounting ans stack up your sheets, it will be a huge figure. Also that's why the default rounding up/down behavior in .Net (not sure about other programming languages) is to the next even value, also called bankers' rounding, to minimized error in accounting comparing to our normal "human" way of rounding.

Read this page for clearer explanation and a special class to handle money. [Code Project : A Money type for the CLR](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MoneyTypeForCLR.aspx)

Also about [Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)

Comment: -1 because this answer is misleading. Decimal is a data type specially made to store money correctly. Doing calculations is a different kind of problem and depends on the context: if you want to divide money in equal shares without losing money, you should use a dedicated function/method/class that does this correctly for it (see http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html).

The referred article on Code Project is based on some invalid assumptions: not understanding that Decimal is stored as base 10, test that also succeed with Decimal, but assumes that they will fail.